# Do Doc Hudson's tires being on the ground symbolise not being able to let go of his past?

Tags: cars, pixar

I didn't learn this till I was an adult, but apparently "X hung up his racing tires" means "X retired".

When Lighting discovers one of Doc's trophies, we see a racing tire *on the ground,* hidden behind boxes of garbage. Does this mean he metaphorically never locked them away or moved on to the next part of his life?

Comment: I'm a long-time motorsport fan and have never heard that expression before. Idiomatically, it doesn't make much sense, because the tires usually belong to the team, not the driver. I *have* heard it used as "X hung up his helmet", but Doc obviously doesn't have one of those.

Comment: The expression is the functional equivalent of the expression of a retiring footballer *hanging up his boots*.

Comment: They aren't LITERALLY hung up, just put away as they are no longer needed.

Answer (score 4):

1. hang up his boots (soccer)
2. hang up his gloves (boxing)
3. hang up his helmet (american football)
4. hang up his spikes (track & field)

These are some of the variations of the expression meaning: *step down* or *retire*.